# bash: sleep process not getting killed

Tags: bash, shell, signals, sleep

I wrote a simple bash script which does nothing but sleeps.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Sleeping..."
sleep 180s
```

I see two processes running on my system after I run the script:

```
user 22880  0.0  0.0  12428  1412 pts/28   S+   20:12   0:00 /bin/bash ./sleep.sh
user 22881  0.0  0.0   7196   356 pts/28   S+   20:12   0:00 sleep 180s
```

I give a `SIGTERM` to the process with id `22880` by using `kill -15 22880` which kills the process. However, after this, I still see the sleep command running which exits after 180 seconds.

```
user 22881  0.0  0.0   7196   356 pts/28   S    20:12   0:00 sleep 180s
```

Why does this happen? What do I need to do to not leave the `sleep 180s` process running?

Comment: weird... I tried your script (with sh and ./) ps -aux doesn't return anything anymore after kill -15 of the process number, how do you display the list of process, with ps -aux ?

Comment: Yes. I did a `ps aux | grep sleep`. The process still remains even if I give a `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Ok I understand now, this is the process of grep not your script, try ps -aux |grep idontexist :)

Comment: @Anyone_ph Not sure if that is true. The grep process comes as: `user 22887  0.0  0.0  11744   912 pts/29   S+   20:13   0:00 grep --color=auto sleep` which is different than the `sleep 180s` process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`kill -15 22880` will send a signal to the shell executing the script, but not the `sleep` command. To send the signal to every process in the process *group*, you should be able to specify a *negative* process ID.

```
kill -15 -22880
```

Alternately, ensure that the script kills its children before exiting.

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
echo "Sleeping..."
sleep 180s & wait
```

If you leave `sleep` in the foreground when the signal is received, the shell must wait until it exits before running the trap; `sleep` is uninterruptible. The workaround is to run it in the background, then `wait` on it. `wait`, being a shell built-in, can be interrupted, so that the trap runs immediately and kills any background processes still in progress.

Comment: This is a good reference that explains what you have said: http://riccomini.name/posts/linux/2012-09-25-kill-subprocesses-linux-bash/

Answer (score 1):

you can also use **killall sleep** or **kill -9/15 $(pidof sleep)**

9 use to kill the process and 15 use to terminate the process

```
bash$ ps -ef|grep sleep
pratik   24775  2695  0 23:44 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 600
pratik   24778 24690  0 23:44 pts/29   00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
bash$ killall sleep 
bash$ ps -ef|grep sleep
pratik   24792 24690  0 23:44 pts/29   00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
bash$
bash$ ps -ef|grep sleep
pratik   24978  2695  0 23:52 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 600
pratik   24981 24690  0 23:52 pts/29   00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
bash$ kill -15 $(pidof sleep)
bash$ ps -ef|grep sleep
pratik   24986 24690  0 23:52 pts/29   00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep`
```