# Docker bash shell script does not catch SIGINT or SIGTERM

Tags: bash, docker, shell, sigint, sigterm

I have the following two files in a directory:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM debian

WORKDIR /app
COPY start.sh /app/

CMD ["/app/start.sh"]
```

`start.sh` (with permissions 755 using `chmod +x start.sh`)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
trap "echo SIGINT; exit" SIGINT
trap "echo SIGTERM; exit" SIGTERM
echo Starting script
sleep 100000
```

I then run the following commands:

```
$ docker build . -t tmp
$ docker run --name tmp tmp
```

I then expect that pressing Ctrl+C would send a SIGINT to the program, which would print SIGINT to the screen then exit, but that doesn't happen.

I also try running `$ docker stop tmp`, which I expect would send a SIGTERM to the program, but checking `$ docker logs tmp` after shows that SIGTERM was not caught.

**Why are SIGINT and SIGTERM not being caught by the bash script?**

Answer (score 6):

Actually, your `Dockerfile` and `start.sh` entrypoint script work as is for me with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, provided you run the container with one of the following commands:

- `docker run --name tmp -it tmp`
- `docker run --rm -it tmp`

#### Documentation details

As specified in [`docker run --help`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/):

- the `--interactive` = `-i` CLI flag asks to *keep STDIN open even if not attached*
  (typically useful for an interactive shell, or when also passing the `--detach` = `-d` CLI flag)
- the `--tty` = `-t` CLI flag asks to *allocate a pseudo-TTY*
  (which notably forwards signals to the shell entrypoint, especially useful for your use case)

#### Related remarks

For completeness, note that there are several related issues that can **make `docker stop` take too much time and "fall back" to `docker kill`**, which can arise when the shell entrypoint starts some other process(es):

- First, when the last line of the shell entrypoint runs another, main program, don't forget to prepend this line with the `exec` builtin:
  `exec prog arg1 arg2 ...`
- But when the shell entrypoint is intended to run for a long time, trapping signals (at least `INT` / `TERM`, but **not** `KILL`) is very important;
  {see also this SO question: [Docker Run Script to catch interruption signal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50257930/9164010)}
- Otherwise, if the signals are not forwarded to the children processes, we run the risk of hitting the "PID 1 zombie reaping problem", for instance
  {see also this SO question for details: [Speed up docker-compose shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50534605/9164010)}

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that bash will not handle signals until the foreground process terminates, the `sleep 10000` in your case. Your traps do work, but you would have to wait 10000 seconds first.

Your fix is

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=
trap 'echo SIGINT; [[ $pid ]] && kill $pid; exit' SIGINT
trap 'echo SIGTERM; [[ $pid ]] && kill $pid; exit' SIGTERM
echo Starting script
sleep 10000 & pid=$!
wait
pid=
```

Also you probably want to replace trapping specific signals with trapping any exit

```
trap 'echo EXIT; [[ $pid ]] && kill $pid; exit' EXIT
```

These and more are very well explained at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#When_is_the_signal_handled.3F

Comment: Shouldn't the trap commands be single-quoted? (due to the `kill "$pid"` inside)

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to just use the `--init` flag.

```sh
docker run --init [MORE OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Per their [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run)...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+C sends a signal to `docker` running on that console.
To send a signal to the script you could use

```
docker exec -it <containerId> /bin/sh -c "pkill -INT -f 'start\.sh'"
```

Or include `echo "my PID: $$"` on your script and send

```
docker exec -it <containerId> /bin/sh -c "kill -INT <script pid>"
```

Some shell implementations in docker might ignore the signal.
This script will correctly react to `pkill -15`. Please note that signals are specified [without the `SIG` prefix](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trap.1p.html).

```
#!/bin/sh
trap "touch SIGINT.tmp; ls -l; exit" INT TERM
trap "echo 'really exiting'; exit" EXIT
echo Starting script
while true; do sleep 1; done
```

The long `sleep` command was replaced by an infinite loop of short ones since `sleep` [may ignore some signals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438469/2834978).

Comment: `CTRL+C sends a signal to docker running on that console.` That makes sense, however i'm still confused why SIGTERM is not being caught

Comment: You are setting a trap inside the container but sending the signal from its outside. It's not caught because it never reaches there

Comment: From what I understand: `docker stop` sends SIGTERM to the main docker process. The main docker process is `bash /app/start.sh`. Therefore, the bash process should be receiving SIGTERM, which I expect would write SIGTERM to stdout then exit. However, that does not seem to be happening.

Comment: That's right. You could try creating a file instead of an echo `trap "touch term.tmp; exit" SIGTERM` to check if the signal is trapped. Docker is not probably showing the echo if it ever happens.

Comment: Just tried, the file isn't being created either. It seems like the signal simply isn't being caught by the script